# How do I get ng-select to update when scope is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table above a form, that when a row is selected it populates a form with data. That form has a select element. Upon the first row in the table being selected, the data populates correctly and the correct selected option is shown. On the second and subsequent selection the correct selected option is not shown. In chrome dev tools I can see the values update properly, but it is not visually shown.

What am I missing? How do I get that correct option to be visually shown?

```
<select name="updateCategory" ng-model="selectedPermission.permission.category_id">
       <option value="{{cat.id}}" ng-selected="cat.selected" ng-repeat="cat in selectedPermission.permission_categories">
              {{cat.name}}
       </option>
</select>
```

Here is function in controller that is updating the scope.

```
         $rootScope.$watch('toolBarSelectedValue',function(){
            if($rootScope.toolBarSelectedValue >0){
                Permissions.getItem($rootScope.toolBarSelectedValue).then(function(res){
                    var pc = res.data.permission_categories;
                    var p = res.data.permission;
                    angular.forEach(pc,function(v,k){
                        if(v.id == p.category_id){
                            pc[k].selected = true;
                        }else{
                            pc[k].selected = false;
                        }
                    });
                    $scope.selectedPermission = {"permission":p,"permission_categories":pc};
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }else if($rootScope.toolBarSelectedValue == 0 || $rootScope.toolBarSelectedValue == null){
                $scope.selectedPermission = {};
            }
        });
```

Comment: why don't you fire an event upon selection instead of using $watch?

Comment: I would use ng-options as opposed to <option...></option> you can then relate your selection to your ng-model easily. See docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: There are more than 1 directives being utilized here. it was easier to use $rootScope. Although I'm new to this, so maybe it's improper.

Comment: Yeah, you should use ng-options with an ng-model attribute with a $scope variable. Can you show us your new code?

Comment: Alright, ng-options solved the issue. I thought it didn't work, but I made a spelling mistake. please submit answer to get credit.

Comment: @Jax700303 Share an example in an answer. Everyone will benefit of it :)

Comment: @Okazari see answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ng-options as opposed to `<option...></option>` you can then relate your selection to your ng-model easily. See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for more info.

Something like:

```
<select name="updateCategory" ng-model="cat" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in selectedPermission.permission_categories">
</select>
```

bear in mind I am not sure of you data structure, but this should get you on your way.

Comment: One note that caused confusion for me in the documentation is, as it reads: select as label for item in array. it's easier to understand like: value as label for item in array